# How to approach rigging a mouth with a separate lip mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm looking to animate a character that has a separate pair of lips that sit on the outside of the mouth cavity of the main model. What's the best way to approach? I need:

1) The lips and mouth opening need to correspond w/ one another. When one moves, the other moves in a similar way

2) The lips need to be attached to the model but a separate mesh

Also, any tips on best practices for animating this type of setup? There will be a lot of lip syncing involved.
[image]

Comment: it's not a problem if your lip mesh is separate from the rest of the character, but it would simplify your work if you join it to make a single object, then, when you'll parent with automatic weight, mouth and lips should work together, and anyway you can bring some corrections in Weight Paint mode or with the Vertex Group assign button... for the lip sync here is a good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FIEzAlnVvw&

Comment: When you say "join it," to mean simply combining the two meshes? Or to sculpt out the lips with the existing body mesh?

Comment: yes combine the 2 meshes

Comment: Got it, I think I have something I can work with. Thanks!